# Prolog membership predicate

Tags: list, prolog

I need to write a Prolog predicate that avoids redundant answers with items occurring multiple times in the list at hand, as shown in the following sample queries:

```
?- member(a, [a, b, a]).
true
?- member(X, [a, b, a]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
false.
?- member(X, [a, b, a, c, a, d, b]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
false.
```

I know that the following would output all of them regardless of the repeats:

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X, T).
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare both clauses, are there cases, where both apply?

```
member(X, [X|_T]).
member(X, [_Y| T]) :- member(X, T).
```

Just compare both clauses' heads to each other.  Or, let Prolog do it for you:

```
?- member(X, [X|_T]) = member(X, [_Y| T]).
   X = _Y, _T = T.
```

So the `_Y` and `X` must be the same. When are they the same? Always, if the first clause is true! So we need to exclude that case by adding a further condition that in the second clause, they must be different.

```
memberd(X, [X|_T]).
memberd(X, [Y| T]) :- dif(X,Y), memberd(X, T).
```

```
?- member(X, [a, b, a, c, a, d, b]).
   X = a
;  X = b
;  X = a
;  X = c
;  X = a
;  X = d
;  X = b
;  false.
?- memberd(X, [a, b, a, c, a, d, b]).
   X = a
;  X = b
;  X = c
;  X = d
;  false.
?- memberd(a, [a, b, a, c, a, d, b]).
   true
;  false.
```

The last query can be improved using `library(reif)` which I use in Scryer, but which is also available for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl)|[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl):

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).
memberd(E, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(E = X, true, memberd(E, Xs) ).

?- memberd(a, [a, b, a, c, a, d, b]).
   true.
```