# Stopping infinite loop in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, infinite-loop

I'm trying to return distinct items in a list. I've come up with the following code. I seem to run into a problem when checking the members of the list using member(X,Y), and it runs into an infinite loop.

```
get_unique(Y, [H|T]) :-
   memberchk(H, Y)->  get_unique(Y, T) ; get_unique([H|T], T).
get_unique(_, []) :- true.

final_list(X, L) :-
   get_unique(Y, L), member(X,Y).
```

There are two input cases:

```
?- final_list(dog,[dog,cat,bat,dog]). 

true;
true;
true;
true;
(infinitely)
```

In this case I would expect just

```
true;
false.
```

The other input case:

```
?- final_list(X,[dog,cat,bat,dog]).

X = dog;
X = cat;
X = bat;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
(infinitely)
```

In this case I would expect just

```
X = dog;
X = cat;
X = bat;
false.
```

I tried to do some debugging and I think I can see that member(X,Y) is generating the infinite loop -- tracing steps seen below. I don't know how to stop this, such that member stops checking once it returns bat.

```
X = bat ;
   Redo: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat|_6882]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, _6632|_6888]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) final_list(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, dog]) ? creep
true ;
   Redo: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, _6886|_6888]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, _6886, _6632|_6894]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) final_list(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, dog]) ? creep
true ;
   Redo: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, _6886, _6892|_6894]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, _6886, _6892, _6632|_6900]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) final_list(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, dog]) ? creep
true ;
   Redo: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, _6886, _6892, _6898|_6900]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, _6886, _6892, _6898, _6632|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) final_list(_6632, [dog, cat, bat, dog]) ? creep
true ;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61134135/772868) for a similar problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try `get_unique/2` alone:

```
?- get_unique(Y,[dog,cat,bat,dog]).
   Y = [dog,cat,bat|_A].
%                   ^^^
```

Thus, `Y` is only a **partial list**, but not a (real) list. It comprises all lists with three or more elements.

The second clause should read `get_unique([], []).` to avoid this problem. And also the first needs some rearrangement:

```
get_unique(Y, [H|T]) :-
   ( memberchk(H, T) ->  get_unique(Y, T) ; Y = [H|Y1], get_unique(Y1, T) ).
%                 ^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^             ^^
get_unique([], []).
```

But still, your definition makes some odd assumptions:

```
?- final_list(X,[dog,Cat]).
   X = dog, Cat = dog.
```

So it forces variables to become one specific value.

There is no clean way out of this, except by reconsidering `member/2`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61134135/772868) for a clean solution. Here is the answer `memberd/2` produces:

```
?- memberd(X,[dog,Cat]).
   X = dog
;  X = Cat, dif(Cat,dog)
;  false.
```

So the answer says: `X = dog` as before and additionally, `X = Cat` but only if `Cat` is different to `dog`.