# Prolog membership predicate without dif or when

Tags: prolog, logic

The following prolog logic

```
memberd(X, [X|_T]).
memberd(X, [Y| T]) :- dif(X,Y), memberd(X, T).
```

will produce

```
?- memberd(a, [a, b, a]).
true
?- memberd(X, [a, b, a]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
false.
?- memberd(X, [a, b, a, c, a, d, b]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
false.
```

is there prolog logic that can be used to produce the same result without using **when()** or **dif()** function or anything from a loaded prolog library. Just using pure logic?

Comment: `dif/2` **is** pure logic!

Comment: @GuyCoder: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61133211/772868).

Comment: Before using this site, you need to [get informed](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first.

Comment: I rolled back your question to version 1. If you want to ask follow-up questions, feel free to do so, but do not change the contents of the question to the point of (potentially) invalidating already given valid answers.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question literally, just use:

```
?- setof(t, member(X, [a,b,a]), _).
   X = a
;  X = b.
```

However, some answers will be suboptimal:

```
?- setof(t,member(a,[a,X]),_).
   true
;  X = a.  % redundant
```

... whereas `memberd/2` answers in perfection:

```
?- memberd(a,[a,X]).
   true
;  false.
```

In fact, if you use `library(reif)` with

```
memberd(E, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(E = X, true, memberd(E, Xs) ).
```

you get the best answer possible:

```
?- memberd(a,[a,X]).
   true.
```